# create CSV from list of print output

Tags: python, csv

I have managed to connect to API and retrieve information in list;

```
`for elem in root:
   for subelem in elem.findall('.*/*/')[:6]:
         print(subelem.text)
```

`
the output is list of line;

- id 92708ea6-c866-4206-a222-2e8bed58c3dd
- ASP
- FREE_TEMPORARILY
- 04/17/2017 15:44:26
- false
- id bb48c170-e004-47eb-8707-06a9c0eccb0d
- Cloned from Edutech Year Subscription
- STANDARD
- 04/04/2019 12:04:42
- true

I want to create CSV from this list with column describing each of this line [id, nam, date,etc.] 
struggling to find a way to create this. would appreciate any help

Please note there spaces between the first id and second series of lines (2 list)

Comment: checkout the python standard library csv module, here's a tutorial https://realpython.com/python-csv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new, i suggest you look at [the tutorial on data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), specifically the `append` method.

You can use it like this:

```
sub_elements = []
for elem in root:
    for subelem in elem.findall('.*/*/')[:6]:
        sub_elements.append(subelem.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
with open('somename.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for elem in root:
        csv_writer.writerow([x.text for x in elem.findall('.*/*/')[:6]])
```

If you need headers on this CSV, you might want to use `csv.DictWriter` instead of `csv.writer`.

Comment: HI again,  I'm getting this line,only elements.  ://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/LicenseManager}name' at 0x0000024DBAB7B090>,<Element '{http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/LicenseManager}subscriptionType' at 0x0000024DBAB7B130>,<Element '{http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/LicenseManager}dateCreated' at 0x0000024DBAB7B180>,<Element '{http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/LicenseManager}terminated' at 0x0000024DBAB7B220>,<Element

Comment: Try the corrected version. If it still gives wrong results, please show what really is in `root`.

Comment: Yes, this showing now the list separated  by ", " in but 12 empty line at the top,   anyway I'm now trying to write header  "
with open('somename.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
      fn = ['id', 'name', 'date']
      csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames='fn', restval='', extrasaction='ignore')
      csv_writer.writeheader()
      for elem in root:
            csv_writer.writerow([x.text for x in elem.findall('./*/*/')[:4]])"